# .net Framework and my application vb

Tags: vb.net, frameworks

I made application in visual basic 2010 .

How can i know which version of .net framework my application require to work ?

What about if i use `Win 7 ? Win xp ?`

Comment: That's what you specified when you started the project.  Project + Properties, Application tab, Target framework setting if you forgot.

Comment: Go to `My Project` > `Application` > `Target framework`.